# How do return false if the String contains a space between letters?

Tags: java

Sub characters can only be either a member of alpha, digit, a dollar sign or an underscore.

Given a string, determine if it's a valid identifier. I've done most of it.

```
public class IdentifierChecker {
    public static boolean isValid(String idn) {
        // here's your code...
        boolean valid = false;

        if (idn.length() > 0) {
            char firstChar = idn.charAt(0);

            if (Character.isLetter(firstChar) || firstChar == '_'
                    || firstChar == '$') {

                for (int i = 1; i < idn.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(idn.charAt(i))
                            || Character.isDigit(idn.charAt(i))
                            || firstChar == '_' || firstChar == '$') {
                        valid = true;
                    } else {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Here is the syntax for valid identifiers:

Each identifier must have at least one character.

The first character must be picked from: alpha, underscore, or dollar sign. The first character can not be a digit.

The rest of the characters (besides the first) can be from: alpha, digit, underscore, or dollar sign. In other words, it can be any valid identifier character.

Examples of valid identifiers:

```
i
wo_rd
b2h
```

Examples of invalid identifiers:

```
1i
wo rd
!b2h
```

Comment: Break the loop when `valid=false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
               if (Character.isLetter(idn.charAt(i))
                        || Character.isDigit(idn.charAt(i))
                        || firstChar == '_' || firstChar == '$')
```

should be:

```
               if (Character.isLetter(idn.charAt(i))
                        || Character.isDigit(idn.charAt(i))
                        || idn.charAt(i) == '_' || idn.charAt(i) == '$')
```

Since you would reject identifiers with '_' or '$' anyplace than at the start.  Also, you should stop the loop once valid is set to false, otherwise valid will be based on the last character in the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In your else block, since any invalid condition makes the entire string invalid, add

```
break;
```

After

```
valid = false;
```

in your else block.

This sets the return value, and stops further cycles of the for loop.

Comment: Nitpick: I was always taught to have one entry and one exit point from a method/function as it improves readability and reduces the risk of missing the return statement buried deep somewhere in the code

Comment: Agreed, I was taught that as well. Would break; be most appropriate here then?

Comment: Personally, that would be one of my choices

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public class IdentifierChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isValid("i"));
        System.out.println(isValid("wo_rd"));
        System.out.println(isValid("b2h"));
        System.out.println(isValid("1i"));
        System.out.println(isValid("wo rd"));
        System.out.println(isValid("!b2h"));
        System.out.println(isValid(""));

    }

    public static boolean isValid(String idn) {
        // here's your code...
        boolean valid = false;

        if (idn.length() > 0) {
            char firstChar = idn.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isLetter(firstChar) || firstChar == '_' || firstChar == '$') {
                for (int i = 0; i < idn.length(); i++) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(idn.charAt(i)) || Character.isDigit(idn.charAt(i)) || idn.charAt(i) == '_' || idn.charAt(i) == '$') {
                        valid = true;
                    } else {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression, you can simply do:

```
static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_$][\\w_$]*");

static boolean isValid(String idn) {
  return PATTERN.matcher(idn).matches();
}
```

`[a-zA-Z_$]` matches exactly one character in the range `a-z` and `A-Z` and either `_` or `$`.

`[\\w_$]` matches zero or more characters in the range `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` and `_` or `$`.

Testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // valid identifiers:
  System.out.println(isValid("i")); // true
  System.out.println(isValid("wo_rd")); // true
  System.out.println(isValid("b2h")); // true
  // invalid identifiers:
  System.out.println(isValid("1i")); // false
  System.out.println(isValid("wo rd")); // false
  System.out.println(isValid("!b2h")); // false
  System.out.println(isValid("")); // false
}
```